# What is @{..} expression in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Reading List</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/style.css}"></link>
</head>
```

While i am developing a spring boot project,according to some requirment i want to add/load some static resource content by using thymeleaf.while loading/referencing the css file i am using a thymeleaf tag.

> th:href="@{/style.css}

Can anyone Explain me why we are using the expression '@' ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [link expressions](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html)

> link expressions, a type of Thymeleaf Standard Expression: `@{...}`

Just put `@` before the link so Thymeleaf identify the expression as a link

Specifically you are using a context-relative URL

> Context-relative URLs start with `/`

Answer (score 1):

```
variable expression:"${}"
selection variable expressions:"*{}"
message expressions:"#{}"
link url:"@{}"
```

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#creating-and-configuring-the-template-engine - 4 Standard Expression Syntax

Answer (score 0):

Think of `@{...}` in Thymeleaf like your savvy friend who knows all the shortcuts in town. In your Spring Boot project, when you're jazzing up your web pages with Thymeleaf, this little `@` symbol followed by curly braces is your go-to for making sure your web pages know where to find their stylish clothes, i.e., the CSS files, JavaScript, images, you name it.

Let's take a closer look at your line of code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/style.css}">
```

Here’s the breakdown:

- `th:href`: This is like saying, "Hey Thymeleaf, I want you to handle the 'href' part of this link." It's Thymeleaf's way of knowing it needs to step in and do some magic.
- `@{...}`: Imagine this as your navigator. It tells Thymeleaf how to find the exact location of your CSS file in the big world of your project. It's like giving GPS coordinates to Thymeleaf so it doesn't get lost.
- `/style.css`: This part is straightforward – it's the name and location of your snazzy CSS file.

In simple terms, using `@{...}` in Thymeleaf is like giving a smart GPS to your web page. It helps ensure that all references to your style sheets, scripts, and images are spot on, no matter where your web app is hosted or how it's configured. It's a neat trick to make sure your web app looks great and finds its resources, no matter where it goes!